# Button creating HTML code

Tags: html, button

I want to create a table that will have rows added to it when a button is pressed. Is there any way to do this? I have looked online and haven't been able to find anything.

EDIT: I am looking for a solution that utilizes Javascript to add HTML code when a button is pressed. I don't know how feasible this is, for I am new to Javascript. I am wanting to have a  table with rows of text fields, and have a new row with text fields be added to the table when a button is pressed.

Comment: What language are we talking about here?  Javascript?  C#?  Need more info.

Comment: This can be accomplished in several ways. It's too much to address a complete solution in a SO answer though. Pick a technology and give it a try, then post specific questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you need some JavaScript to append rows to your table. I've set use a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/kbsvd/ that might help you.

```
function addRow() {
    var td, tx;
    var tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for(var x=0; x<2; x++ ) {
        td = document.createElement("td");
        tx = document.createTextNode(".");
        td.appendChild( tx );
        tr.appendChild( td );
    }
    tbl.appendChild( tr );
}
```

The HTML is

```
<input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Add Row" onClick="addRow();">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="tbl" border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dummy </td>
    <td>Dummy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I looked at the JSFiddle, and edited the line that tells it what to put in the new cells. I couldn't figure out how to put an input tag in there. Is that possible?